# Outlook add-in: is there a way to change the icon of my plugin in dynamic way inside the function file?

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I need to change the plugin icons according to the user status, 
is the a way to do it in the JS functionFile, 
and in the XML just to put the default value?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the feature: dynamic icon change, you requested, is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins